# Mongoose pre('save') doesn't add created_at

Tags: express, mongoose, save, schema

I have following problem. When i want to post new Book to my database i also want to add created_at variable. I am just express 4 and mongoose. Actually my code works, but it doesn't add created_at ( but others are added ).

**post function**

```
import { Books } from './../schemas/book.schema';
class BookRouter {
    private postBook(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const book = {
            title: req.body.title,
            author: req.body.author
        };  
        Books.create(book, (err, book) => {
            if(err)
                return res.status(404).send(err);
            return res.status(200).send(book);
        });
    }
}
```

**and my schema class**

```
import { NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
class BookSchema {
    private bookSchema: Schema;
    constructor() {
        this.setSchema();
    }
    public getBookSchema(): Schema {
        return this.bookSchema;
    }
    private setSchema() {
        this.bookSchema = new Schema({
            createdAt: Date,
            title: String,
            author: String
        }).pre('save', (next: NextFunction) => this.preSave(next));
    }

    private preSave(next: NextFunction) {
        if(!this.bookSchema.get('createdAt'))
            this.bookSchema.set('createdAt', new Date);
        next();
    }
}
const book = new BookSchema;
export const Books = model('Books', book.getBookSchema());
```

Any ideas? Doing it like 6hours and haven't found solution.

Comment: Why not just pass `timestamps: true` to your schema? That way a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` is automatically generated. You can also set it so the name is `created_at` instead of the default `createdAt`

Comment: But what if i want to use bcrypt and crypt my password, it's the same problem with pre method :/

Comment: Is it typescript you're using?

Comment: Yes. I have found that if i use normal function(next) { this.createdAt = new Date() }; it is working, but with arrow function it's not. Why?

Comment: Arrow functions does not have their own `this`. See this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: So i cannot use arrow function in this case, yep?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your middleware to:

```
private preSave(this: Document, next: NextFunction) {
    if(!this.bookSchema.get('createdAt'))
        this.bookSchema.set('createdAt', new Date);
    next();
}
```

Replace Document with your document definition.

HTH.